# How do I type an acute accent on the Russian PC keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, language, unicode

I need to write an acute accent over over a Russian letter to [indicate stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet#Diacritics). [Google tells me](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20macos) to switch to QWERTY, hold the letter key and select the accented one. This types a U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE, but I'm using Cyrillic letters, not Latin letters and what if my letter isn't in the Latin alphabet, like И?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20240103192554/https://uc80d1fe1b7ad562806d71731ce0.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/CKoC10DYKYqjdMUd-rE5PLIm5GtCwgybC7iUryM8MhvrHwxrPQ0qiJRqHempsT7vBWZmfykCWcuX3ck91_bnHnxv6cVx68bvqBfLKdMCiVmpIJxrqyZyadYurTOy1yMt-nCG7Mk6Li2RwgDZhPzb3W0W/file?_download_id=10404368098258598605316893999049804144784425578729554317818312838&_notify_domain=www.dropbox.com&dl=1/Russian%20Stress.keylayout.zip?dl=0) is a custom layout I made once which lets you put in the stress marks on Russian text.

The combining acute character needed for this is also available in the ABC Extended keyboard at Option Shift e, or in the Character Viewer at U+0301

Comment: On QWERTY I can type an acute accent with Option Shift e and then a letter to put the accent on, but when I switch to QWERTY, type Option Shift e then switch back to Russian to type the letter, the accent goes away.

Comment: The Qwerty keyboard cannot produce the character you need, which is the (separate) combining acute accent that you type after the base letter.  The Qwerty keyboard uses a deadkey system to produce characters which already have the accents attached to them. If you type Russian and then use ABC Extended to type option shift e, you can get things like ю́

Comment: Dropbox files are pretty temporary by nature; do you mind if I add this file to archive.com, so that there is a more permanent reference for people seeking the same thing in the future?

Comment: @Alex. By all means, good idea!